# List index out of range error when using mouse events functions with tensorflow for object detection

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, mouseevent, object-detection-api

I am using Tensorflow for object detection. I successfully trained the neural network and it can detect the object I want to detect in the livestream. It does this by making a bounding box around the object.

Now I want to mark areas in the video frame(initially) such that if the object comes in the marked area and is detected,(i.e. if a bounding box is made in the marked area) then I want to print a message in the terminal.

For this purpose, I am using OpenCV. I found a nice tutorial on how to use Mouse callback functions to do this. The link is given below.

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/03/09/capturing-mouse-click-events-with-python-and-opencv/

But there is an error when I execute my code. The error is shown below.

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-10159c26292b> in click_and_crop(event, x, y, flags, params)
    201           refPt.append((x,y))
    202           cropping = False
--> 203           cv2.rectangle(image_np,refPt[0],refPt[1],(0,255,0),2)
    204       ret, image_np = cap.read()
    205       # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have 
shape: [1, None, None, 3]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

My main program is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import six.moves.urllib as urllib
import sys
import tarfile
import tensorflow as tf
import zipfile

from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
from PIL import Image

import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


# This is needed since the notebook is stored in the object_detection 
folder.
sys.path.append("..")

from object_detection.utils import ops as utils_ops

if tf.__version__ < '1.4.0' and tf.__version__ != '1.10.0':
raise ImportError('Please upgrade your tensorflow installation to v1.4.* or 
later!')


# ## Env setup

# In[3]:


# This is needed to display the images.
#get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')


# ## Object detection imports
# Here are the imports from the object detection module.

# In[5]:


from utils import label_map_util

from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util


# # Model preparation 

# ## Variables
# 
# Any model exported using the `export_inference_graph.py` tool can be 
loaded here simply by changing `PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH` to point to a new .pb 
file.  
# 


# In[6]:


# What model to download.
MODEL_NAME = 'car_inference_graph'

# Path to frozen detection graph. This is the actual model that is used for 
the object detection.
PATH_TO_CKPT = MODEL_NAME + '/frozen_inference_graph.pb'

# List of the strings that is used to add correct label for each box.
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join('training', 'object-detection.pbtxt')

NUM_CLASSES = 1


# ## Download Model

# ## Load a (frozen) Tensorflow model into memory.

# In[7]:


detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
  od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
  with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
  serialized_graph = fid.read()
  od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
  tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')


# ## Loading label map
# Label maps map indices to category names, so that when our convolution 
network predicts `5`, we know that this corresponds to `airplane`.  Here we 
use internal utility functions, but anything that returns a dictionary 
mapping integers to appropriate string labels would be fine

# In[8]:


label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, 
max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)


# ## Helper code

# In[9]:


def load_image_into_numpy_array(image):
  (im_width, im_height) = image.size
  return np.array(image.getdata()).reshape(
  (im_height, im_width, 3)).astype(np.uint8)


# # Detection

# In[10]:


# For the sake of simplicity we will use only 2 images:
# image1.jpg
# image2.jpg
# If you want to test the code with your images, just add path to the images 
to the TEST_IMAGE_PATHS.
PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR = 'test_images'
TEST_IMAGE_PATHS = [ os.path.join(PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR, 
'image{}.jpg'.format(i)) for i in range(1,44) ]

# Size, in inches, of the output images.
IMAGE_SIZE = (12, 8)


# In[11]:


def run_inference_for_single_image(image, graph):
  with graph.as_default():
  with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Get handles to input and output tensors
    ops = tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()
    all_tensor_names = {output.name for op in ops for output in op.outputs}
    tensor_dict = {}
    for key in [
      'num_detections', 'detection_boxes', 'detection_scores',
      'detection_classes', 'detection_masks'
  ]:
    tensor_name = key + ':0'
    if tensor_name in all_tensor_names:
      tensor_dict[key] = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(
          tensor_name)
    if 'detection_masks' in tensor_dict:
      # The following processing is only for single image
      detection_boxes = tf.squeeze(tensor_dict['detection_boxes'], [0])
      detection_masks = tf.squeeze(tensor_dict['detection_masks'], [0])
      # Reframe is required to translate mask from box coordinates to image 
  coordinates and fit the image size.
      real_num_detection = tf.cast(tensor_dict['num_detections'][0], 
  tf.int32)
      detection_boxes = tf.slice(detection_boxes, [0, 0], 
  [real_num_detection, -1])
      detection_masks = tf.slice(detection_masks, [0, 0, 0], 
  [real_num_detection, -1, -1])
      detection_masks_reframed = utils_ops.reframe_box_masks_to_image_masks(
          detection_masks, detection_boxes, image.shape[0], image.shape[1])
      detection_masks_reframed = tf.cast(
          tf.greater(detection_masks_reframed, 0.5), tf.uint8)
      # Follow the convention by adding back the batch dimension
      tensor_dict['detection_masks'] = tf.expand_dims(
          detection_masks_reframed, 0)
    image_tensor = 
  tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

    # Run inference
    output_dict = sess.run(tensor_dict,
                         feed_dict={image_tensor: np.expand_dims(image, 0)})

    # all outputs are float32 numpy arrays, so convert types as appropriate
    output_dict['num_detections'] = int(output_dict['num_detections'][0])
    output_dict['detection_classes'] = output_dict[
        'detection_classes'][0].astype(np.uint8)
    output_dict['detection_boxes'] = output_dict['detection_boxes'][0]
    output_dict['detection_scores'] = output_dict['detection_scores'][0]
    if 'detection_masks' in output_dict:
      output_dict['detection_masks'] = output_dict['detection_masks'][0]
return output_dict


# In[12]:


# In[10]:

with detection_graph.as_default():
  with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
    while True:
      refPt = [] #ROI code starts from here
      cropping = False

    def click_and_crop(event,x,y,flags,params):
      global refPt,cropping

      if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        refPt = [(x,y)]
        cropping = True

      elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        refPt.append((x,y))
        cropping = False
        cv2.rectangle(image_np,refPt[0],refPt[1],(0,255,0),2) # ROI code end
    ret, image_np = cap.read()
    # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, 
  None, None, 3]
    image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
    image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
    # Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was 
  detected.
    boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
    # Each score represent how level of confidence for each of the objects.
    # Score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
    scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
    classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
    num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
    # Actual detection.
    (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
        [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
        feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
    # Visualization of the results of a detection.
    vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
        image_np,
        np.squeeze(boxes),
        np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
        np.squeeze(scores),
        category_index,
        use_normalized_coordinates=True,
        line_thickness=8)

    cv2.imshow("object detection", image_np)
    cv2.setMouseCallback("object detection", click_and_crop)

    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
      cv2.destroyAllWindows()
      cap.release()
      break
```

Using this code:

- I can see the livestream properly.
- The desired object is successfully detected.
- But as soon as I drag the left mouse button to draw ROI in the frame, I get 
  the error mentioned above.

I understand this has something to do with `refPt[0],refPt[1]` but I don't understand where to make the necessary changes!

Technical information:

1. Tensorflow 1.10
2. OS - Ubuntu 18.04
3. Python 3.6
4. OpenCV 3.4.2

Please help.

Thanks :)

Comment: why the definition of this function `def click_and_crop(event,x,y,flags,params):` is inside a loop? also, refPt = [] is inside a loop... you click down... it has something, then it gets deleted in the next iteration then button up and you add another item, but only 1 is there and you try to access 2

Comment: @api55 Yeah! So where do you think I should put it?

Comment: @api55 I put the whole `def click_and_crop(event,x,y,flags,params):` function and the two lines above it together above **with detection_graph.as_default():** now there is no  out of range index error but I can't see the rectangle when I draw it. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems in your code, but basically the problem can be summarized in the scope of the variables you are using.

1. avoid creating a function in a loop... this will redefine a function every time... not a problem here, but it is better not to do it.
2. You have a `refPt = []` inside the while, this will empty the array at every iteration... as in case 1, it should be outside. Anyways you have in the function `refPt = [(x,y)]` that will remove old values and "clean" the variable.
3. Inside the function you have `cv2.rectangle(image_np,refPt[0],refPt[1],(0,255,0),2)` which changes `image_np`, but this image gets changed locally and not globally.
4. In the loop you have `ret, image_np = cap.read()` which will remove any rectangle almost immediately without being displayed.... you need to draw the rectangle on the new images. Something like:

---

```
 ret, image_np = cap.read()
 # if no image was obtained quit the loop
 if !ret:
   break
 tmpPt = refPt.copy() # to avoid it being changed in the callback
 if len(tmpPt ) ==2:
   cv2.rectangle(image_np,tmpPt [0],tmpPt [1],(0,255,0),2)
```

---

5. It is recommended to use `cv2.setMouseCallback("object detection", click_and_crop)` outside the loop... You can use `cv2.namedWindow("object detection")` to create the window without having the image.

These are the problems I see, maybe you encounter more once these are corrected...One more thing, you are just drawing a rectangle, but I do not see that you are actually using it to select a roi (cropping the image to the rectangle size), I do not know if this is intended...

I hope this helps you, and if you have a question, just ask in a comment.

---

#### UPDATE

To make myself a little bit clear and to add the selection first and then the detection part, the code should look like this:

```
refPt = [] 
cropping = False

def click_and_crop(event,x,y,flags,params):
  global refPt,cropping

  if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
    refPt = [(x,y)]
    cropping = True

  elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
    refPt.append((x,y))
    cropping = False

cv2.namedWindow("object detection")
cv2.setMouseCallback("object detection", click_and_crop)

detect = False
with detection_graph.as_default():
  with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
    while True:
     ret, image_np = cap.read()
     # if no image was obtained quit the loop
     if !ret:
       break
     tmpPt = refPt.copy() # to avoid it being changed in the callback
     if len(tmpPt ) ==2:
       cv2.rectangle(image_np,tmpPt [0],tmpPt [1],(0,255,0),2)

    if detect:
      # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
      image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
      image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
      # Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected.
      boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
      # Each score represent how level of confidence for each of the objects.
      # Score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
      scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
      classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
      num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
      # Actual detection.
      (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
          [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
          feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
      # Visualization of the results of a detection.
      vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
          image_np,
          np.squeeze(boxes),
          np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
          np.squeeze(scores),
          category_index,
          use_normalized_coordinates=True,
          line_thickness=8)

    cv2.imshow("object detection", image_np)

    key = cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF 
    if key == ord('q'):
      cv2.destroyAllWindows()
      cap.release()
      break
    elif key == ord('s'):
      detect = True # start detecting
```

Once again this will only draw the rectangle... it does not crop

Comment: thanks! I put the code from `ref = []` to `cropping = False` above ` with detection_graph.as_default():` i.e. outside the while loop. I also put `cv2.namedWindow` and `cv2.setMouseCallback` after the break in while loop.i.e the break happens when I press "q" key. Even with these modifications (that you mentioned) how could it retain the drawn box and show it? as it will always update `ret,image_np = cap.read()` at every frame! With this code I see the video stream and try to draw boxes but no box is seen and after I press "q" I have a window very small "object detection" with no frame.

Comment: My target is to start the video stream, mark the areas and then continue the stream for now. So it should refresh image_np at every frame **while retaining** the rectangular box drawn on the image frame. I think I need to pause and capture that one frame and draw the box and then continue, as if I make the box then as it is livestream, the box will not be drawn on one particular frame but on successive frames,right? how do I pause and draw and then resume? I hope you undestood my doubt.

Comment: @Winbuntu the namedWindow and setMouseCallback was to do them outside the loop... To retain the drawn box that is with the part number 4... look at my update

Comment: tried the update but it shows a small window named "object detection" which is black. Says Kernel appears to have died and nothing what is intended happens! I do not know why. Alternatively, As the area in which the object should be detected and the camera capturing it are fixed in location, I tried to pass the fixed co-ordinates of that area to the rectangular function and now when I switch on the camera the rectangles are already there. But I have the next task which is related to these rectangles. I stored these two rectangular functions in two variables namely a and b.

Comment: Now, I am trying to make a logic like `if boxes in a: print("object1")` or  ``if boxes in b: print("object2")``. So that I know two places is occupied with those two objects. But the problem is, a and b when printed have values in matrix array form and are nothing but modified version of image_np  with two rectangles. How do I write code to see "if there are boxes detected(that means object detected since there are no false detections) in a and/or b (in the rectangles) then print something. How do I compare box coordinates with rectangle coordinates. This is my final task.